# Rayleigh quotient for non symmetric matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, numerical-linear-algebra

Suppose that we have two rectangular matrix $X\in\mathbb{R}^{n_{1}\times p}$ and $Y\in\mathbb{R}^{n_{2}\times p}$. We define $A=X^TX\in\mathbb{R}^{p\times p}$, and $B=Y^TY\in\mathbb{R}^{p\times p}$.

How could I find the condition for
$$x^T AB x>0\quad \text{for any nonzero vector}~x\in\mathbb{R}^{p}.$$

Since $AB$ is not symmetric anymore, I attempt to work on "AB+BA" but things are not that easy.

Any help appreciated!!!!!!

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "I attempt to work on 'AB + BA'"? What did you try to do with this matrix?

Comment: Your statement holds if and only if $\lambda_{\min}(AB + BA) > 0$. Does that answer your question, or was that your starting point and the reason you "attempt to work on 'AB + BA'"? In the second case, please explain why the condition $\lambda_{\min}(AB + BA) > 0$ is not sufficient for your purposes so that we can know what kind of condition you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Actually, in what I am working on, $Y$ is a submatrix of $X$. Thus, I expect more to derive from $\lambda_{min}(AB +BA)$. How could I use the property like both $A$ and $B$ are PSD and $Y$ is a submatrix of $X$. May be only SVD will help?

Comment: I'm not sure how the SVD would help here

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer per se, but just a statement that it's going to be hard to come up with simple conditions that ensure this. Here's a counterexample that fits the description of your situation in the comments.

$$
X = \left[\begin{matrix}1 & 0\\-1 & 1\\4 & 0\\9 & 2\end{matrix}\right], \quad 
Y = \left[\begin{matrix}1 & 0\\-1 & 1\end{matrix}\right], \quad A = X^TX, \quad B = Y^TY
$$
We find that $\lambda_\min(AB + BA) \approx -31$. $x^TAx < 0$ holds with $x = (1,10)^T$.